# Why does this pattern not match QUERY_STRING  in RewriteCond while it matches in preg_match?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd

Here is what I have in my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^(run=[a-z0-9A-z]{13})$
RewriteRule %{QUERY_STRING}  \? [L]
```

All I am doing is Rewriting the `QUERY_STRING` for all `QUERY_STRING` similar to `run=4f13665700694` and do nothing. A URL example: `http://thinkingmonkey.me/runs/?run=4f13665700694`. So, the RewriteCond should Match. But the above does not work.

But, the pattern seemed correct. Since, *both [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) & [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) use [`PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions`](http://www.pcre.org/)*.

I tried it using `preg_match`.

```
$subject = "run=4f13665700694"; 
$pattern = "/^(run=[a-z0-9A-z]{13})$/";

echo preg_match($pattern, $subject);
```

And as excepted the above will output:

```
1
```

i.e. a successful match.

*I do not understand why. What am I missing here?*

Comment: Your `RewriteCond` should match, but you'll have to clarify what you're going after with that `RewriteRule`, as it won't work as written.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I am trying to remove the `run=..` part and just redirect the URL to the index there. The URL looks like this: `http://thinkingmonkey.me/runs/?run=4f13665700694`. So, the `RewriteCond` should Match.

Comment: So, you're trying to maintain the current URL exactly, except strip the query string?  Is that correct?

Comment: @ShaneMadden Yes. And load the `index.php` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so, this will take a request to `/runs/` with the 13-character alphanumeric `run` parameter as the only thing in its query string, strip the query string, and rewrite to `/runs/index.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^run=\w{13}$
RewriteRule ^/runs/?$ /runs/index.php? [L]
```

Comment: what does the `w` in `^run=\w{13}$` stand for? and I cannot use %{QUERY_STRING} in a RewriteRule?

Comment: `what does the w in ^run=\w{13}$ stand for?` Equivalent to what you had, except it adds `_`.  `and I cannot use %{QUERY_STRING} in a RewriteRule?`  The place where you had it is the URL pattern, not the string that you're checking; the argument order isn't the same as `RewriteCond`.